# Asp.net gridview overridding bootstrap table styles

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

So I just messed around for quite a while with an issue where asp.net grid view was overriding bootstrap styles for tables.  The table rows were not using the bootstrap borders and instead were using an ugly black border provided by the user agent style sheet.  After inspecting the page and finding that an attribute of rules=all was present which seemed a little out of place.  I stumbled on this link when googling how to remove it [removing rules all](http://www.ytechie.com/2008/04/removing-rulesall-from-the-rendered-table-from-a-gridview/).  The answer was to add a 
    `GridLines="None"`
attribute to the grid view declaration which fixed the issue.  Anyways, just posted this to help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a  `GridLines="None"` attribute to the grid view declaration which fixed the issue.